# Rails separated seeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seeding

Hi i probably have a simple question.

I have this database with `moodboard templates`. 
I want to transport it to the server with `capistrano` but in my **seeds.rb** file there is only all the `seeds` and if i run them again a lot of data gets inserted twice.

I normally run:

```
rake db:seed
```

But i would like to see another command

How can i make a separate `seed` file to execute on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either delete your seeds before insert in `seeds.rb` or check the count of the model rows or check for the `id` if the item you're looking to insert before you insert it in your `seeds.rb`.  Basically, I think you just need to add some checks before you insert additional data.  I could provide a more specific answer if you posted your `seeds.rb`.